# Sharepoint 2013 search query tool find property bag items

Tags: search, property-bag

I created a sharepoint app with which you can create and edit property bag items. You can of course only edit the items you created yourself. Now I would like to make the property bag items searchable, but to correctly do this, I'm trying to first retrieve property bag items using the search query tool.

I'm trying to find the right way to write a query to find those property bag items. (I created a searchable property bag item using SP designer).

Answer (score 2):

Once you have created a Managed property and made it searchable.

1. Run full crawl.
2. Create a managed property for the crawled property created for this property bag.Make the managed property searchable and retrievable.
3. Use it in query just like any other normal managed property.

for eg: Prop:Value